How does the weak / strong shock solution work?
In this chart, you can see that there are 2 possible angles for a shock to be at when both the deflection angle and Mach number are the same.
Circled in red is the line of an object going Mach 2, and it has a definition angle of 15 degrees.
How is this shock able to have 2 different angles at the same speed and deflection angle?
What is different?


The flow will almost always prefer the weak shock solution.
The strong shock will occur in situations where the back pressure is substantially higher.  This won't happen in an external flow -- because the back pressure will generally eventually be the ambient pressure (the pressure in front of the shock).
So, we're looking at internal flows instead -- inlets to engines.  If the back pressure is too high, the strong shock solution will occur.
You may have heard about 'inlet unstart' occurring with the SR-71 and other aircraft.  This is a situation where the engine is operating normally -- then something occurs that causes the back pressure to increase.  This forces the inlet shocks to switch from the weak to strong shock solution, which then messes up the flow into the engine.
Before they developed a computer to help quickly re-start the inlets, this was a very violent incident and the pilots had to descend and slow down to get the inlets operating properly again.
So there is your next clue to situations like this (where there are multiple solutions).  Sometimes the solution you end up at depends not only on the conditions at that moment -- but also on the history of how you got there.  This property in physics is called hysteresis.
So under normal operation, the inlet sees the weak shock solution -- but once it is unstarted, it sees the strong shock solution.  The fix is to back away from that flight condition until a weak shock solution is obtained and then accelerate back to the initial condition maintaining the weak shock solution.  This is hysteresis in action.

I see, so basically because the shock is stronger it is able to turn the flow the same even at a higher shock angle? (The only reason it is stronger is because it needs to be, due to higher back pressure)

Or, you could look at it as the shock is stronger, therefore the pressure jump is higher.  Importantly, the flow downstream of the strong shock is subsonic -- the flow downstream of the weak shock is supersonic.
